# Javascript data not loading at first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, object

I have the following code, it have one problem, on first load it wont display anything, but when I press `next` button on my carousel, everything will work perfectly, so the problem resides somewhere on the first call, as the other calls are exactly the same but theese are working :S

I wont put where the display code, as it is working because it's only jquery adding data to divs and stuff, but as I said, on first time, data is empty.

```
var dificildecision = function() {
}

dificildecision.prototype = {
    is_animating : false,
    base_url : window.base_url,
    current_decision : null,
    decisiones_seen : 0,
    historial_decisiones : {
        "decisiones" : []
    },
    is_previous : false,
    previous_id : 1,

    next_decision : function(replace) {
        if (this.is_animating != true) {
            this.is_animating = true;
            if (this.is_previous) {
                decision = this.get_decision(this.previous_id);
            } else {
                if (this.get_current_decision() === false)
                    decision_id = 1;
                else
                    decision_id = this.current_decision.id;
                this.get_new_decision(decision_id);
                decision = this.get_current_decision();
                $('#decision-carousel').html("This is: " + decision.key);
                this.is_animating = false;
                this.is_previous = false;
            }
        } else {
            // console.log("Slow down");
        }
    },

    get_new_decision : function(decision_id) {
        if (typeof (decision_id) === "undefined" || decision_id === null) {
            decision_id = 1;
        }
        $.getJSON('http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value', this.set_current_decision);
    },
    get_current_decision : function() {
        return (this.current_decision) ? this.current_decision : false;
    },
    set_current_decision : function(decision) {

        // THIS DOESN'T WORK
        this.current_decision = decision;

        // THIS WORK SECOND+ TIME EXECUTED
        //dificildecision.prototype.current_decision = decision;
    }
};

    var dificil = new dificildecision();
    dificil.next_decision(true);
$('#testlink').on('click', function(){
    dificil.next_decision(true);
});
```

With this code nothing is displayed on console, but if I change

`set_current_decision : function(decision) {
        this.current_decision = decision;
    }`

to

`set_current_decision : function(decision) {
        dificildecision.prototype.current_decision = decision;
    }`

It outputs the object only when the carousel function is handled, but not at page load...

I've also tried to change

`get_new_decision : function(decision_id) {
        if (typeof (decision_id) === "undefined" || decision_id === null) {
            decision_id = 1;
        }
        $.getJSON('/~robhunter/dificildecision/web/app_dev.php/new/'
                + decision_id, this.set_current_decision);
    },`

to

`get_new_decision : function(decision_id) {
        if (typeof (decision_id) === "undefined" || decision_id === null) {
            decision_id = 1;
        }
        $.getJSON('/~robhunter/dificildecision/web/app_dev.php/new/'
                + decision_id, dificildecision.prototype.set_current_decision);
    },`

But exactly as original code, nothing is displayed ever :S

You can try it out here http://jsfiddle.net/TUX5a/

Comment: Since adding to the prototype affects new instances a constructor, I think you should be using `this` inside your prototype functions to refer to the instance, and not the name of the function itself. e.g. `if( this.is_animating != true ){ this.is_animating=true;` // etc

Comment: @czarchaic this is even worst, doing that it never loads anything :S

Comment: I can't get it working on a fiddle... Maybe because the prototype stuff or I don't know (never used fiddle to create anything)

Comment: See fiddle @czarchaic http://jsfiddle.net/TUX5a/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  //  window.dificildecision = new dificildecision();
      var dificildecision = new dificildecision();
}
```

And use `this` inside your `dificildecision.prototype.next_decision`

**Explanation:**

When you declare your function using this line: `function dificildecision()` in global scope, there will be a new property named `dificildecision` assigned to your window object.
When you call `window.dificildecision = new dificildecision();`, this property (a reference to a function) ***is replaced*** with an instance

=> this would cause unpredictable behavior in the application and should be avoided.

**Update after the OP created a fiddle:**

I have checked your fiddle, you have problem with asynchronous nature of ajax. When you call `decision = this.get_new_decision();`, you fire an ajax request to server to get the decision. And the next line you call `decision = this.get_current_decision();`, the decision is not set yet ( the callback set_current_decision is not run yet).

There are 2 solutions to this problem:

- Use synchronous ajax by using `$.ajax` function with `async: false`. However, this solution is not recommended because it will block the browser and degrade user experience.
- Use callback or promise API (recommended). Below is a demo how to do this:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/TUX5a/1/)

Return a promise from getJSON

```
get_new_decision : function(decision_id) {
    if (typeof (decision_id) === "undefined" || decision_id === null) {
                decision_id = 1;
    }
  return $.getJSON('http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value', this.set_current_decision); 
}
```

And return it again inside `next_decision`:

```
next_decision : function(replace) {
        if (this.is_animating != true) {
            this.is_animating = true;
            if (this.is_previous) {
                decision = this.get_decision(this.previous_id);
            } else {
                if (this.get_current_decision() === false)
                    decision_id = 1;
                else
                    decision_id = this.current_decision.id;
                decision = this.get_new_decision(decision_id);

                this.is_animating = false;
                this.is_previous = false;
            }
        } else {
            // console.log("Slow down");
        }
        return decision;//this could be a promise or a value.
    },
```

Use [$.when](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) to execute a callback when data is ready, if the parameter is not a promise, the callback will be called immediately (considered it as a resolved promise):

```
$.when(dificil.next_decision(true)).then(function(decision){
        $('#decision-carousel').html("This is: " + decision.key);
});
```

This code is just a demo of how to use promise API, you may need to restructure your code to make it fit into this programming model.

Comment: @user1381537: did you also change to `var dificildecision = new dificildecision();`?

Comment: Yes, I've also did that, and replacing dificildecision.whatever to this.whatever, when doing this, it doesn't work even when it worked before

Comment: @user1381537: Check if you replace the `this` correctly. After replacing `this` in  `dificildecision.prototype.next_decision`. You also need to replace `dificildecision.set_current_decision` with `dificildecision.prototype.set_current_decision` in your $getJSON

Comment: Tried that, nothing works, see my update, I've changed code to work in a better way, I've found also an anormal behaviour with `set_current_decision` method

Comment: @user1381537: I have checked your fiddle, you have problem with asynchronous nature of ajax. When you call `decision = this.get_new_decision();`, you fire an ajax request to server to get the decision. And the next line you call `decision = this.get_current_decision();`, the decision is not set yet ( the callback `set_current_decision` is not run yet)

Comment: That was something I was thinking about, but as I don't know how to do it better, I didn't made any change... How can I fix it to set the callback correctly?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, actually is nice how it works, but the problem is the same with `set_current_decision(decision)` even with your code, that variable still `null` after ajax call! I need to set it = data retrieved to handle the previous/next etc workflow. With async false i got everything working perfectly, but I like your answer more, only problem is that null variable...

Comment: @user1381537: that's just a `demo` how to do it asynchronously. In order to apply this approach, you have to restructure your code to fit into this programming model. That's just a recommendation, feel free to choose an approach that you like. I'm glad that you also like this answer, thanks.

Comment: The problem was that on set_current_decision i needed to use dificildecision.proto... instead of this.curr.... now it's working perfectly :) (i've adapted everything) thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Actually I've found that I needed to change `get_new_decision` method to use `$.ajax` instead of `$.getJSON` and set  `async: false` to store variable this way

```
get_new_decision : function(decision_id) {
        if (typeof (decision_id) === "undefined" || decision_id === null) {
            decision_id = 1;
        }
        $.ajax({
            async : false,
            type : 'GET',
            url : '/~robhunter/dificildecision/web/app_dev.php/new/'
                    + decision_id,
            dataType : 'json',
            // data: myData,
            success : function(data) {

                dificildecision.prototype.set_current_decision(data);
            }
        });
    },
```

And change into `set_current_decision` method to use `this.current_decision = decision;` :)
With this change, everything works perfectly!

Comment: this solution works but it's not recommended. Check my answer with a solution using promise API